# Android: Compiler warnings in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-warnings

In android studio, when I build my project my event log says `Compilation completed successfully with 102 warnings in 52 sec`. Where can I see these compiler warnings?
I know about `Analyze -> Inspect Code` which is not what I want. I also tried building my application using ant script with

```
<target name="-warn">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/com/mobile" fork="true"  debug="true">
        <compilerarg line="-Werror -Xlint:all"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

This shows some warnings when even fixed does not reduce the compilation warnings. What's the right way to do?

Comment: Did you look in the Messages view?

Comment: @EricWoodruff `View -> Tools Window -> Messages` is disabled

Comment: What about Problems? I have both of these enabled but I run a Gradle build.

Comment: @EricWoodruff I'm sorry. Is problems in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, there are both Messages and Problems views available

Comment: @EricWoodruff Where can I find it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45839/discussion-between-rani-and-eric-woodruff)

Answer (score 4):

These all errors will be visible in Event Log, placed on bottom right corner of Android Studio(I am running 0.4.2 currently).

[image: Event Log]

You can open **Event log** by double click on error messages as well.

For some messages description will also be available on **Gradle Console**, generally placed beside **Event Log**.

Comment: While it's true that you can double-click on error messages to navigate to them, this doesn't appear to work for warnings. I have yet to find a way to get an overview of all errors and warnings.